# could not find artifact issue in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am new to J2EE.I am having an issue in pom.xml.
My `pom.xml` is like this:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>atom</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>ATOM</name>
<!-- Shared version number properties passed down to modules -->
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.5.11</slf4j.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
    <junit.version>4.8.2</junit.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.resourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</project.build.resourceEncoding>
</properties>
<modules>
    <module>atom-domain</module>
    <module>atom-presentation</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<description>New ATOM Project</description>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.bah</groupId>
    <artifactId>atom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

I have an error in `<parent>` tag.I am unaware of fixing it. My error report is like this:

```
 The project com.bah:atom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (D:\eclipse_code\J2EE_workspace\atom\pom.xml) has 1 error
 [ERROR]   Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.bah:atom:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 45, column 10 -> [Help 2]
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 3):

Add `<relativePath>` parameter to parent `<parent>`

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>com.bah</groupId>
    <artifactId>atom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <relativePath>../pathtopom/my-parent-pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

**or** install parent pom before.
Execute
`mvn clean install -f my-parent-pom.xml`

Comment: @llya But our file dont have any other parent pom file.

Comment: My file dont have any other parent pom file.

Comment: @AnazA what is in `parent` tag. This is artifact with parent pom

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you need and `parent` and `modules` tags? Usually there is no need of any of this tag, unless you want one pom file to build all modules at once ('maven reactor' http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html)  Use `dependency` and throw out parent-child structure.

Comment: I am unaware of dependency.Can you suggest me any tutorials

Comment: um. You already use it, but still unaware. Look at `<dependency>` tag in any pom. Documentation http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html